# Are there good reasons NOT to have a physical “unmount” button on USB thumb drives?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

There are always the odd cases where file loss happens due to people unplugging USB drives without unmounting them.

Some users find the unmount process (at least on on windows) to be tedious or mysterious, whereas a hardware unmount button could be simple and intuitive. However I’ve never seen or heard of such a button on a thumb drive.

Is there a technical reason these buttons don’t seem to exist? Or is it simply not a priority, and would take a lot of work to coordinate and standardize amongst a wide range of software and hardware companies?

Comment: IMO, the process should never be controlled by hardware.

Comment: How would such a button prevent a user from pulling out a drive during a data transfer? USB drives with activity LEDs are a thing and they do a far better of indicating when it is safe to unplug the drive.

Comment: How would a cold storage USB device with a physical "hardware unmount" button be able to keep up with the ever changing nature of operating systems and all the updates they receive? Wouldn't Apple or Microsoft just have to make one minor change to the way drives are managed for this magic button to all of a sudden stop working as expected??

Answer (score 3):

It's not impossible, but likely wouldn't be reliable.

The actual "unmount" procedure is not something that the USB thumbdrive is really in control of. It is primarily a job for *the OS* running on your computer – the unmount doesn't do anything special to the flash media physically, but the OS must **flush all pending writes** (not just writes currently in progress, but writes that have been delayed for later<sup>1</sup>).

As the pending data is still in the host computer's RAM and hasn't reached the USB thumbdrive yet, there's nothing much that the thumbdrive could do except send some kind of "eject request" signal to the OS.

AFAIK, such an "eject request" signal is *possible,* as actual removable-media drives – e.g. CD drives – already do this kind of thing whenever you ask to remove the CD.

However, the unmount/flush needs some time to finish (sometimes a few seconds, sometimes a whole minute if you *just* dropped a huge file into the USB stick). With a physical button though, I suspect that people would treat it the same way as they treat mechanical lockout buttons (like the squeezy thing on DisplayPort connectors) and would yank the USB stick as soon as they've pressed the button, which would actually increase the chances of it happening in the middle of a write being performed.

(And not just in terms of the data being missing – I've heard that flash storage can be physically damaged if power is lost while writing a sector, e.g. SSDs have capacitors to avoid that.)

But an explicit unmount isn't actually required when you're sure that there are *no* pending writes that would need to be flushed. If I remember correctly, all recent Windows versions use a very short flush timer for filesystems on removable media, somewhere around 2 seconds – so as soon as you've saved a file, it's enough to wait a few seconds for it to settle and then you can unplug it.

<sup>1</sup>(SSDs and HDDs may have on-disk DRAM buffers that the disk itself would need to flush in this situation, but USB sticks are too cheap for that – so writes are typically buffered in host OS RAM for a few seconds because doing them synchronously would be significantly slower.

In older Windows versions, I believe the default for USB sticks was to perform no buffering at all, as enabling it led to a long interval tuned for internal media – so you had to choose between quick-unplug and performance. Newer Windows versions do enable buffering but automatically tune the flush timeout depending on what kind of device it is.)

Answer (score 0):

I expect your hypothesis that its a lot of work for no $$$ is correct.

While no doubt technically possible, I also expect that from a reliability POV you likely don't want people putting pressure on the disk while its writing as that could cause worse corruption if the interface is loose.

Also, it would mean more cost, more complexity and additional standards, while causing confusion for users who may not know if the drives need to be ejected in hardware.  Importantly, even if done in hardware it still will take time for the OS to write the files (and notify the user)

Have a look at https://www.usbmemorydirect.com/blog/write-caching-explained/ - TIL that by default Windows disables write caching on USB devices - which should mean that if you get a device with an activity indicator (led) and that is off you should be OK to just pull the drive. I'd also format the disk as ntfs if appropriate to take advantage of journalling just in case, if practical.